# Generate bin file for Altera FPGA

Tags: vhdl, fpga, intel-fpga, quartus

I need to generate the bin file for an Altera FPGA using Quartus 16.1

I can generate the sof file, RBF or Jic file, but I cant find any place to generate the bin file.

I need it because the custom software that we use to upgrade the FPGA uses this format, and there is no manual or guidance to generate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the sof2flash and then flash2bin application within Nios Console.

Using one after the other will get you a bin file.

Comment: There is no flash2bin application, only bin2flash.

Comment: I'm sorry, it should be nios2-elf-objcopy instead of flash2bin. Try this one and it should work.